# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file "Debug/

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to run C++ code in microsoft visual version 6.0. The code is well compiling but I'm getting the error "fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file "Debug/Assignment.exe" when I try to build. The file is saved in the project named Assignment. I'm new to C++ and the microsoft visual stuff. I don't know where to start from to get around error. Please help.

Comment: You might want to consider upgrading to a version which isn't 16 years old - there have been 7 new major versions since 6.0! You can [get the latest Express edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) for free. The Express editions are fine for beginners, and in most cases perfectly adequate even for professionals.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will do just that.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like a copy of the exe (Debug/Assignment.exe) is already running so visual studio can't overwrite the file. Have a look in the task manager / process explorer and kill any copies that are running then try again.

Comment: What is the task explorer in VS?

Comment: @okey_on thanks for the correction (first person to pick the error in 4.5 years ;-) . task manager or process explorer. Not task explorer. If you still don't know what I mean google will help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Curiously, in my case it was a CMake 'debug' linker library path setting that caused almost the same error, and I guess you can have similar problems with 'optimized.obj' linking failures.

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'debug.obj'

Answer (score 1):

This is because the compiler doesn't have access to that file. Change the project directory and try again.

Answer (score 1):

For me this error started coming when I turned on Preprocessing output
Project properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessing -> Preprocess to a file: Yes (/P)